# Recursive Print Function: (Item (a,Item (b,Item (c,d))))

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to devise a recursive function for printing out the contents of string concatenations (e.g. (a,b) represents a concatenation of a and b in the string "ab").

My output should be formatted as follows:
Item (a,Item (b,Item (c,d)))

However, currently my output looks like this:
Item (Item (Item (a,b),c),d)

I am producing the output with this recursive function:

```
std::ostream & Concatenation::print(std::ostream &out) const { 
    out << "Item (";
    getLeft() -> print(out);
    out << ",";
    getRight() -> print(out);
    out << ")";
    return out; 
}
```

How should I change this code to produce the correct output?

Comment: Concatenations are associative, so the output you're getting is equivalent to the output you want.

Comment: Yes, but I want the outputs to be exactly in the same format as Item (Item (Item (a,b),c),d) etc. when being output.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the data. If the `left` element is another concatenation, it has to be printed as `Item(a, b)`, it can't just print `a`.

Comment: You don't print just `a, b` until you get to the base case where both `left` and `right` are strings rather than concatenations.

Comment: So, what changes would you add to the code block above?

Comment: No changes to the code above. I'd change the code that's doing the concatenations, so that it does `Concatenation(a, Concatenation(b, Concatenation(c, d)))` instead of `Concatenation(Concatenation(Concatenation(a, b), c, d)`

Comment: Alternatively, instead of changing the code that's doing the concatenations, is there a fix with the outputting code itself?

Comment: Not easily. The function would have to look deep in the objects that it points to, to figure out that it can swap the order.

Comment: Or it would have to know that it's being called recursively as the left argument from another `print()` function, and not print `Item(` first.

Comment: You could have two methods: `printLeft` and `printRight`. `printLeft` just prints the element without putting `Item(` first.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code that's doing the concatenations and it seems to output correctly now. Before, I was scanning from right to left, now I'm scanning from left to right. I didn't have to change the above code at all, as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer below.